# JSX.IntrinsicElements.div: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>

Tags: reactjs

in this program i am trying to display 3 images using JSX of ReactJS.This code is working perfectly when i use

tag or tag in place of 
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

```
ReactDom.render(
  <div>
    <h1>programmers pic</h1>
    <div>
      <img src="some url">
      <img src="some url">
      <img src="some url">
    </div>   
  </div>,document.getElementById("root");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoveflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. Your question is currently unclear, when you say *This code is working perfectly when i use tag or tag in place of import React*, what do you mean exactly? I think you are missing some code, you should properly format your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your img tags don't have closing tags.
2. Second img tag should have `src` instead of `scr`.

Comment: but in HTML we dont need a closing tag